# Google Sheets dropdown from two different columns

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown

I have one Google sheet with two columns

| Fruit | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 34 |
| Orange | 42 |

I want to create a drop down based off of the data in these two columns, e.g., Apple|34. How can I have the value of the dropdown be the value of 2 columns?

My ultimate goal is to export the data from the sheet as a CSV file and use a script to strip out the "Apple|" in the exported data, leaving only the value of 34. But, while the data is in the Google sheet, I want to show both Apple and 34 so that I can remember what 34 stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the lists with a formula and then reference that range. Formula like this would probably work... then reference the automatic list.

```
=let(firstCol,A2:A,secondCol,B2:B,filter(firstcol&"-"&secondCol,firstcol<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In retrospect this is such an obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion:

You can use this simple apps script to create a drop down based from the `Fruit` and `ID` column

### Script:

```
function createDropdown() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Change this to the sheet name in your spreadsheet
  var data = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues() //Data range
  // Set the range where you want the dropdown to appear
  var cell = sh.getRange('D1'); // Change this to your desired cell


  // Dropdown values
  var dropDownValues = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    options = data[i][0] + "|" + data[i][1];
    dropDownValues.push(options)
  }

  // Create data validation rule
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(dropDownValues)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .build();

  // Set data validation rule to the cell
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)